# How can I apply jQuery event to only one input on page without classes and id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have more divs on one page and they are all kinda same. All of them have text input. In javaScript file there is an event where whenever I press enter in input field it makes a new list in div. The problems is when I press enter it makes a new list on all present divs.

```js
$(".container").on("keypress", "input[type='text']", function(key){
  if(key.which === 13){
    var todoText = $(this).val();
    $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></span> " + todoText + "</li>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="grupa">
<h1>To-Do List<span id="form"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></span></h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">

<ul>
  <li><span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span> Sabah</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Find the closest `.container` then find the `ul` `$(this).closest('.container').find('ul').append(....)` there are lot of questions like this but they are all asked differently

Comment: You do know that the snippet is giving an error?

Comment: Given your html you could jsut use `.next()` but the closest gives you more flexibility

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".container").on("keypress", "input[type='text']", function(key) {
  if (key.which === 13) {
    var todoText = $(this).val();


    $(this).next("ul").append("<li> ... </li>");
    // ^-----^---------------- here's your huckleberry
  }
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dL1sehnp/)**

You might want to grab a parent wrapper element using `closest()` instead, to reduce fragility with your markup. If you add anything between these two this breaks.